# How do I restart offlineimap?

Tags: mutt, imap, offlineimap

I have `offlineimap` running on a cron job with `*/10 * * * * offlineimap -q -u quiet`. Every once in a while it seems to get interrupted, and when that happens I can't restart it. If I try to run it from the terminal I get an error indicating that it is locked:

```
OfflineIMAP 6.5.5
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2+ (v2 or any later version)
Account sync Example:
 *** Processing account Example
 ERROR: Could not lock account Example. Is another instance using this account?
 *** Finished account 'Example' in 0:00
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: Could not lock account Example. Is another instance using this account?

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 240, in syncrunner
    self.lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 207, in lock
    OfflineImapError.ERROR.REPO)
```

Is there any way to break the lock or force `offlineimap` to quit all the way?

Comment: You could run a postsync hook to clean up any lock files... But you are probably better off fixing the interrupts and addressing the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: The cause varies. Usually it is something like closing my laptop in the middle of a sync. It would be nice if there was a way to recover.

Comment: Can you edit your crontab line in to the question? I have no such issues...

Comment: `*/10 * * * * offlineimap -q -u quiet`

Comment: You definitely want something more robust than that. See the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP#Running_offlineimap_in_the_background) if you use systemd, if not, you can use a script to properly daemonize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be resolved in OfflineIMAP 6.6.1.